# 'OR' with GET url parameters

Tags: api, url, hyperlink, get

I have a `GET` API url something like: `/api/countries`.
I want to search from it using multiple parameters like name& code... For that, I will do `/api/countries?name=pak&code=92`
But what if I want to use `OR` in url params e.g. `/api/countries?name=pak`**OR**`code=92`

Comment: What is the purpose of using `or` in URL? are going to use it instead of `&`

Comment: exactly, I want to use same variable twice like `api/countries?name=pakORname=can`

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not a regular API call.
 you can solve this in 2 ways

- Create the logic in your controller where you implement the or statement
- Implement the ODATA REST protocol.

I would prefer ODATA. Entity framework has support for this and you can even implement this on your own created lists.

In ODATA you can use filter expressions:
filter=name eq 610 or code eq 615

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.90).aspx

Comment: then you are just passing parameter. Setting an or statement in the query string is a part of the odata filter. If you implement it this way you should document your api

Answer (score 0):

If you use OR as you have shown in your question then it will not work (`name` will contain the value `pakORcode=92`). If this is something that you would consider doing then you could use `explode` to split into key-value pairs around each OR.

You could maybe also have a third variable, `method`. You could set this to either `AND` or `OR`, then you'd know what method to use?

Hope this helps